# ES search by incorrect phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, i have record in DB:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam et gubergren vulputate

And I would like to find this record by incorrect phrase, like this:

> Lorme

When i'm looking for

> Lorem

everthing is ok and ES return my record.
But it's possible with mistake some char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using elasticsearch version > 2.x then you want to take a look at the 'fuzziness' parameter of a match query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-match-query.html

Also have a read of the parameters section for fuzziness:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/common-options.html#fuzziness

If you are on a version < 2.x then take a look at the fuzzy like this query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-flt-query.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the thing you need **fuzzy matching**:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

[Fuzzy match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field": {
        "query":     "lorme",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
        "operator":  "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```